# how to select User table fields while Retrieving Associated Data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have "users(id, name)" and "userdrivermapping(id,user_id,driver_id)" tables. Both user_id and driver_id is the foreign key of id from users table. I want to display driver name in the user view page. I dont know how to select users fields in table Association. "Name field is always return empty"

Here is the my controller code

```
$id = 7 ;
$query = $this->Users->UserDriverMapping->find()    
    ->contain([
        'Users' => function ($q) use($id) {
        return $q
        ->select(['UserDriverMapping.id,user_id, driver_id,name'])
         ->where(['UserDriverMapping.user_id' => $id]);
        }
        ]);

    foreach ($query as $driver) {

        echo $driverId = $driver->user_id;
        echo $driverId = $driver->name;
    }
```

Comment: Users belongsToMany Drivers through UserDriverMapping? Is this the relationshipd between your tables?

Comment: $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'driver_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);

Comment: You need to specify your model association first.

Comment: please post the result of $query ,